# .NET Core 3.1 Kestrel/Apache stop responding requests

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, kestrel-http-server

I am running an application in .NET Core 3.1 behind an Apache 2.4.41 reverse proxy in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

This application was running for months without any issues, then I added SignalR to the project, just to see connected clients, after SignalR, the Kestrel/Apache randomly stops responding to requests after some hours after the start.

I have no idea how to trace the problem, no exceptions, nothing strange in memory/CPU usage.

Comment: Can you post the signalR code?

Comment: @RubbleFord Thanks, I already solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was was simpler than I thought, just had to increase the `MaxRequestWorkers` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf`, as SignalR mainly uses WebSocket connections which keeps a request worker busy as long as it is connected.

Another possible solution was to change the `HttpTransportType` in the client and force another type, as `ServerSentEvents` for example, but it has other counterparts.