# Dotnet site behind kestrel stops working (Requests return 503 from Apache server)

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, kestrel-http-server

I run .NET core 3.1 app behind in Linux machine with Kestrel behind reverse proxy (Apache).
I constantly push some data to certain endpoint and then relay that data through signalR hub to users:

```
        [HttpPut("{tagName}/live")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Datasource")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(TagControllerFilterAttribute))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutLiveTag(Tag tag, string tagName)
    {
        bool status = await tagRepository.UpdateLiveData(tagName, tag);
        if (status)
        {
            await tagHubContext.Clients.Group(tagName).SendAsync(tagName, tag);
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Users joins and leaves that signalr hub by simply removing them from group:

```
    public class TagDataHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("subscribe")]
    public async Task JoinTagGroup(string tagName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, tagName);
    }
    [HubMethodName("unsubscribe")]
    public async Task LeaveTagGroup(string tagName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, tagName);
    }
}
```

My app runs in deployment for few hours and then when I try use that app's API endpoints or anything related to that app I get 503 response from originated from **Apache**. I really don't know why Kestrel stops working...
When I run `service dotnet-site status` I get that app is still running.

I checked processes in server, I see that dotnet uses lots of resources, but apart from code provided above there is nothing else running in that app:
[image: Procs stats]

Please send help I really don't know how to debug/figure out this on linux server, I would value any suggestion.

I also looked this up and did exactly as this person, but it didn't help me: [apache mpm worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770340/net-core-3-1-kestrel-apache-stop-responding-requests)